# Azure CosmosDB not returning results with UDF in Where clause

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I made a UDF in my Azure CosmosDB so that I can query records where the `Timestamp` field equals a certain year.

For example, my query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.StaticKey = 'd6c5a92203d84ce28b94cfc64a6ad4ce' 
AND udf.YEAR(c.Timestamp) = '2020' OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1
```

But for some reason my query always returns 0 results. I have a lot of records in my table that have a datetime from this year.

This record for exmaple DOES return 1 row and prints `2020`:

```sql
SELECT udf.YEAR(c.Timestamp) FROM c WHERE c.StaticKey = 'd6c5a92203d84ce28b94cfc64a6ad4ce' OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1
```

My UDF in Azure looks like this:

```js
function YEAR(datetimeString){
    var datetime = new Date(Date.parse(datetimeString));
    return datetime.getFullYear();
}
```

The column `Timestamp` contains datetime values looking like this: `2020-10-20T07:13:22.802346`.

As you can see in this fiddle the javascript function works good: https://jsfiddle.net/0eozyhnv/

Anyone any idea why my UDF isn't working in my `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UDF returns an integer. So you should write the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.StaticKey = 'd6c5a92203d84ce28b94cfc64a6ad4ce' 
AND udf.YEAR(c.Timestamp) = 2020 OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1
```

But note that this is relatively slow since UDFs can't make use of indexes. If you can format your dates in the format accepted by Cosmos DB (`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.fffffffZ`) you could also use the built-in function `DATETIMEPART('yyyy', c.Timestamp)=2020`.

However, I suspect the fastest solution would be `STARTSWITH(c.Timestamp, '2020')` since this makes use of a range index on `Timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks, also for the suggestions! I had no idea that there was a `DATETIMEPART` function. I will use that one from now on.